# How is the current measured in this setup?

Tags: current-measurement

I came across [this](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/30949/en/) article where they measure the current called leakage current, but they are not using an ammeter or DMM.

I couldn't understand what(which device) they use to measure the current. What is the way of measuring current and what device is used in this case?

Comment: From teh overview : "This document will discuss the technical details of testing the input leakage current on semiconductor devices using a test system created with the PXI platform. To learn more about the hardware components of this system, click here. " Link appears to be broken but you can take the hint, and search for more information on the "PXI platform" which incorporates the hardware used. Another image mentions the PXI 4130 "Source Measurement Unit" https://www.ni.com/en-gb/shop/select/pxi-source-measure-unit?modelId=123163

Comment: @user1245: It's good practice to put enough information in your question so that it can be understood on its own. As this question stands readers have to follow an external link to understand it and if the link dies the question is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using source-measure units (SMU). These are devices that combine voltage, current, charge, power, and energy, measurment with a variable power supply.

Comment: Do you know what is the advantage of this SMU over the other traditional ways of current measurement?

Comment: that depends what you consider traditional,  I've never used a benchtop multimeter so I don't know what features they offer.